# Symfony + Doctrine functional database testing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, functional-testing

I found only a few lines about database functional testing in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html

The problem is:

1. I need to install database schema from `dev` database to `test` database before testing.
2. I need to reinstall fixtures before each test.

It's not described in the documentation. How can I do it using symfony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this command to do same job :

In console line :

```
doctrine:database:create --env=test

doctrine:schema:create --env=test

doctrine:fixture:load --env=test
```

Comment: Can I write fixtures in yml instead of PHP classes? Also can I copy my `dev` schema to `test` database instead of creating new database from annotations?